# Could not retrieve response from web service for xamarin forms

Tags: c#, web-services, xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Hi I am new to programming and I am still a student trying to learn C# and I am supposed to retrieve the response from the web service but I couldn't and it is unable to enter both the if and else statement. How do I resolve this error

**.xaml.cs**

```
private async void GetData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://172.20.129.44/");
    // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //try
    //{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("WebServices/information.svc/GetInformationJSON").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
        //string abc =  dynamicObject["infoOpeningDays"].ToString();
        // List<String[]> dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String[]>>(jsonString);
        //Debug.WriteLine(dynamicObject[0].ToString());
        //string abc = dynamicObject.IEnumerator.[0].IEnumerator.[0].IEnumerator.[0].IEnumerator.[5].Name;
        try
        {
            //  var abc = dynamicObject.GetType().GetProperty("infoOpeningDays").GetValue(dynamicObject);
            String abc = (String)dynamicObject["infoOpeningDays"];
            //JArray v = new JArray();
            //v[0].data,tostring()
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        //Debug.WriteLine(abc.ToString());
        // Debug.WriteLine((string)abc);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("It entered else not if");
    }
    //}
    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{
    //    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    //}
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<Button Text="Get Data" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4282bd" Clicked="GetData"/>
```

**Web service**

```
http://172.20.129.44/WebServices/information.svc/GetInformationJSON
```

**Web service Data**

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Info:#website.Model",
            "infoClosingDays": "Friday",
            "infoClosingHours": "06:00:00 PM",
            "infoID": 1,
            "infoOpeningDays": "Monday",
            "infoOpeningHours": "09:30:00 AM",
            "infoStatus": "Open"
        }
    ]
}
```

Someone Please Save me please

Comment: What is the error message? What do u see in the `HttpResponseMessage response` variable in the debug ??

Comment: @MohitShrivastava it returns me null value and it will throw nullreferenceError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = client.GetAsync("WebServices/information.svc/GetInformationJSON").Result;
```

This might solve your issue.